# Windows command line dectect if there is SymLink folder in path

Tags: windows, command-line, symlink, symlink-traversal

There are here a few solutions to detect if a given folder is a Symbolic Link...

but how to detect if one of the folders in path is a SymLink...
not only the immediate parent... 
but any ancestor folder ???

for example, in the path:

```
c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\file.txt
```

if "dir3" is a Symbolic Link how can i detect it

Answer (score 1):

Batch file, tested on windows 10

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\file.txt"

    for %%a in ("%file%") do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('
        fsutil hardlink list "%%~fa"
    ') do if "%%~pnxa"=="%%b" (
        echo no link
    ) else (
        echo linked
        echo "%%~pnxa"
        echo "%%b"
    )
```

It uses the `fsutil` to retrieve the the real path to the file, checking it against the used path.